# Query not working when I use Jquery $.post

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have this query running fine when I send the form information via post to the process page.  It renders the information expected.  But when I send the post information through a $.post call through jquery I get nothing.  If I omit the part starting with registered_datetime in the query, it works as expected.

I have to believe it's something I'm overlooking.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM leads 
WHERE (first_name LIKE '" . $_POST['name'] . "%' 
OR last_name LIKE '". $_POST['name'] ."%') OR
registered_datetime BETWEEN '". date_fix($_POST['from_date']) ."' AND '" . date_fix($_POST['to_date']) . "'";
```

Here is the index page that has the jquery and form:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#search').keyup(function(){
                $('#test_form').submit();
            });
            $('#test_form').submit(function(){
                $.post(
                        $(this).attr('action'),
                        $(this).serialize(),
                        function(data){
                            $('#results').html(data.html);
                        },
                        "json"
                    );
                return false;
            });
            $('#test_form').submit();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="test_form" action="process.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="search">
        From: <input class="datepicker" type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date">
        To: <input class="datepicker" type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date">
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the process page:

```
require_once('connection.php');
    function date_fix($date) {
        $fix = explode('/', $date);
        $new_date = $fix[2] . '-' . $fix[0] . '-' . $fix[1];
        return $new_date;
    }
    // var_dump($_POST);
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM leads 
               WHERE (first_name LIKE '" . $_POST['name'] . "%' 
               OR last_name LIKE '". $_POST['name'] ."%') OR
               registered_datetime BETWEEN '". date_fix($_POST['from_date']) ."' AND '" . date_fix($_POST['to_date']) . "'";
    // var_dump($_POST);
    // var_dump($query);
    $users = fetchAll($connection, $query);
    $data = array();
    $html = "
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Registered Datetime</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        ";

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $html .= 
            '<tr>
                 <td>' . $user['id']  . '</td>
                 <td>' . $user['first_name']  . '</td>
                 <td>' . $user['last_name']  . '</td>
                 <td>' . $user['registered_datetime']  . '</td>
                 <td>' . $user['email']  . '</td>
            </tr>';
    }
    $html .= '</tbody></table>';

    $data['html'] = $html;
    // echo $data['html'];
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I don't see anything stopping me from stealing all of the information in your database and then erasing it all. Use prepared statements.

Comment: ok have fun stealing the data.  Still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: And it never attempted to. m59 gave you a reasonable advice using a **comment**. That's what they are for.

Comment: OK, I appreciate the concern and maybe I'm really overthinking your statement, but 1. this is a test db on a local storage.  So stealing data is highly unlikely.  Am I missing something?  I asked if there is anything odd looking with the query or the ajax call because it's not retrieving the data as expected.  Not sure why this was voted down.

Comment: @ja408 What if it goes live like this?

Comment: @ja408 have you tried `var_dump($_POST); die;` on your php script, right at the top? The result of your ajax call will show you only what data was sent in `$_POST`. I think your data is not what you expect.

Comment: @m59 I have come so far from this question.  I was so uneducated over a year ago and had no idea what prepared statements were.  Now that is one of the methods I use to insure security on apps I build.  And I laugh at myself blowing up in the comments.  Anyway, sorry for this very unnecessary comment.  but I was looking through my old questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  It actually was the fact I was submitting the form at the end of the script therefore resetting the information being submitted.

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#search').keyup(function(){
                $('#test_form').submit();
            });
            $('#test_form').submit(function(){
                $.post(
                        $(this).attr('action'),
                        $(this).serialize(),
                        function(data){
                            $('#results').html(data.html);
                        },
                        "json"
                    );
                return false;
            });
            $('#test_form').submit(); // IF I OMIT THIS IT WILL WORK AS EXPECTED.
        });
```